# MySql indexing and query optimization and minimum execution time

Tags: mysql, optimization

Currently i am handling records around **600K**, the query below takes a time around *6.5 seconds* to fetch the result.

Could some help me to reduce the execution time to 2-3 seconds?

**QUERY 1:**

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(`LS_CHG_DTE_OCR`, '%Y-%b') AS fmt_date, SUM(connects) AS connects,
        SUM(disconnects) AS disconnects, ROUND(SUM(REV),0) AS REV
    FROM  
      ( SELECT  LS_CHG_DTE_OCR, 
                IF(`TYPE`='Connect',COUNT(DISTINCT ORDER_NO_OHI), 0) AS connects,
                IF(`TYPE`='Disconnect',COUNT(DISTINCT ORDER_NO_OHI), 0) AS disconnects,
                IF(`TYPE`='Upgrade',COUNT(DISTINCT ORDER_NO_OHI), 0) AS Upgrades,
                IF(`TYPE`='Downgrades',COUNT(DISTINCT ORDER_NO_OHI), 0) AS Downgrades,
                SUM(IF(`TYPE`='Connect',REV,0)) AS REV
            FROM  hsd_26_05_2016
            WHERE  LS_CHG_DTE_OCR!=''
            GROUP BY  LS_CHG_DTE_OCR,TYPE 
      ) AS a
    GROUP BY  YEAR(LS_CHG_DTE_OCR), MONTH(LS_CHG_DTE_OCR)
    ORDER BY  LS_CHG_DTE_OCR ASC;
```

**QUERY 2:**

```
 CREATE TABLE `hsd_26_05_2016` (
      `id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `SYS_OCR` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `PRIN_OCR` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `ORDER_NO_OHI` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `SUB_ACCT_NO_OHI` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `SERV_CDE_OHI` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `DSC_CDE_OHI` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `LS_CHG_DTE_OCR` date NOT NULL,
      `SALESREP_OCR` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `CHANNEL` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `CUST_TYPE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `LINE_BUS` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `ADDR1_HSE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `RES_CITY_HSE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `RES_STATE_HSE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `POSTAL_CDE_HSE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `ZIP` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
      `COUNT_SUBS` double DEFAULT NULL,
      `REV` double NOT NULL,
      `TYPE` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `SERVICECATEGORY` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
      `lat` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
      `long` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`LS_CHG_DTE_OCR`,`TYPE`,`ORDER_NO_OHI`),
      KEY `idx2` (`CHANNEL`,`CUST_TYPE`,`LINE_BUS`),
      KEY `idx1` (`RES_STATE_HSE`,`RES_CITY_HSE`,`ZIP`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1134054 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
```

please suggest me if any suggestions in index as well. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: hi Guys , any suggestions please...

Answer (score 1):

That first "counts distinct" by day and type, then sums those counts?  That seems 'wrong'.  If you want the 'uniques' for a month, you can't get it by summing over the days.

That does 2 passes over the data; I think one will suffice.

Consider `GROUP BY LEFT(LS_CHG_DTE_OCR, 7)`

Don't use `ORDER BY  LS_CHG_DTE_OCR ASC` when that value is not available.  Instead, use the same value as in the `GROUP BY`.

If it weren't for the `DISTINCT`, it would be easy to build a "Summary table" to make it much more efficient.  However, [*this blog*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uniques) explains how "uniques" can be rolled up, although with an error of typically 1%.  Is that 'good enough'?

Comment: Thanks Rick James, will implement your suggestions and let me see the how the query performs. Will get back to you. Thanks for your time once again.Cheers :)